# ASP.NET MVC Validate dynamic form elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I want to add the ability to build a form in my app. The user adds input fields to the form in the UI of my app, and for each form element she can specify data-type.

I use ASP.NET MVC 3, and want to use as much as I can of the validation mechanism supported by the frameworks. For my own forms in the app, I decorate each ViewModel with dataannotations to and use client validation.

Is there any way I can add those annotations to a dynamic ViewModel?

It's fine to use e.g. `@Html.TextBox("name")`, but how do I mimic the data annotations, so that jQuery Validate and the unobtrusive plugin picks them up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the data-dash-attributes like this? (Hint: Use an underscore instead of the dash, it will be translated to a dash in the according attribute)

```
@HtmlTextBox("name", new { data_... = "some value", data_... = "some value" })
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I think I need to add some meta data to the JS validator, in order for it to validate my form.